# Атрибуты папок и дисков в java

Tags: файлы, java

Добрый день! Я новичок совсем в java, у меня возник следующий вопрос, отличается ли получение атрибутов папок и дисков от файлов? Я имею ввиду название, размер папки или диска, дата создания, дата изменения.

Вот пример получения атрибута у файла:

```
File file = new File(pach);
if (file.isFile())
{
  //заносим данные в структуру FI
  FI.NameFile = file.getName();
  FI.TypeFile = "file";
  FI.SizeFile = (int) file.length();
  FI.DateCreate = "???";
  FI.DateEdit = new Date(file.lastModified());
}
```

Как получить подобным образом атрибуты у папок и дисков?

Answer (score 3):

Только что попробовал, размер папки с кучей файлов оказался равным 4кб, поэтому, чтобы найти размер всей папки нужно рекурсивно пройтись по всем вложенным папкам и складывать размеры файлов методом file.length()
Стандартного решения по нахождению даты создания файла, к сожалению, нет, придется пользоваться сторонними средствами
Все остальное вроде так же

Comment: спасибо за ответ... буду думать в этом направлении.

Comment: Добавлю лишь, что рекурсивный обход файловой системы — медленная операция, не пытайтесь выполнить её без явного запроса пользователя.

Comment: И еще, погуглив выяснилось, что дату создания файла можно найти с помощью nio

Comment: Я тоже это уже выяснил).

Comment: размер папки тоже можно определить через модуль nio